# When using auto_increment, how do I get the ids of the new rows?

Tags: mysql

My database has,

```
mysql> describe students;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And I'd like to insert 2 students - but I want to know thier IDs immediately

```
mysql> insert into students values (null, 'tom'), (null, 'larry');
```

I'd like it if insert actually returned a result set of the IDs...  aka...

```
mysql> select id from (insert into students values (null, 'tom'), (null, 'larry'));
```

Humm?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to perform both inserts at once and return both new IDs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function to get the first `AUTO INCREMENT` value of the batch and then `MAX` to get the greatest value.

> `LAST_INSERT_ID()` (with no argument) returns a `BIGINT` (64-bit) value representing the first automatically generated value that was set for an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column by the most recently executed `INSERT` statement to affect such a column.

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

```
> INSERT INTO students VALUES (NULL, 'tom'), (NULL, 'larry');

> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM students LIMI 1
```

```
| LAST_INSERT_ID() |
--------------------
|                1 |
```

```
> SELECT MAX(id) FROM students
```

```
| MAX(ID) |
-----------
|       2 |
```

```
> INSERT INTO students VALUES (NULL, 'billy'), (NULL, 'jane'), (NULL, 'fred');

> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM students LIMIT 1
```

```
| LAST_INSERT_ID() |
--------------------
|                3 |
```

```
> SELECT MAX(id) FROM students
```

```
| MAX(ID) |
-----------
|       5 |
```

Comment: This looks interesting.   But it isnt a single transaction... so if others are also currently adding batches of students, I could get the wrong id range (which I could detect by checking students_inserting !=  max - last + 1)

Comment: @BobHerrmann At least, `LAST_INSERT_ID` should work. *The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis.* This means that the client that executed that `INSERT` will get the correct value. Let me do some further research on getting a max.